# Replacement for drupal_add_http_header()

Tags: 8

I have a custom module which are basically APIs, hence require headers like content-type to be added to the responses. I was using `drupal_add_http_header()` in Drupal 7, but it seems to be deprecated in 8. Is there any replacement?

I did read about it on the Drupal website talking about Symfony object Response, but I am unable to use that either.

Comment: As you mentioned, the Symfony Response object is D8's replacement for using drupal_add_http_header. You should address why you can't use it.

Comment: Since it requires me to pass a response object to the function already. Can I achieve the same by using php's header function ?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You should show the code you are using, and give more details. For example, from your description is not clear if you are using a controller or what, and your comment is a little confusing. Why would pass a response object to a function? It is enough you return it to Drupal, but without seeing any code, it is not possible to tell you the code you should use.

Comment: I found a discussion thread from www.drupal.org may be this can be of little help. 1. https://www.drupal.org/node/2307723. 2. https://www.drupal.org/node/2467759.

Comment: You can use `$build['#attached']['http_header']` to add a custom header.

Comment: Related: [How to Register an Event Subscriber in Drupal 8](https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/how-to-register-event-subscriber-drupal8)

Comment: See: [`scheduler_node_view()`/`scheduler.module`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/scheduler/tree/scheduler.module?h=8.x-1.x#n281) for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to modify the headers of a response, you need to use an EventSubscriber. Symphony doesn't have a hook system, but instead uses an event/emitter system. Since it's Symphony driving the request/response cycle, you basically needs to integrate with Symphony to do this.

You could take a look at `\Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\FinishResponseSubscriber` to see how this is done, the gist of it is this:

```
/**
 * Add custom headers.
 */
class HeaderResponseSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
  public function onRespond(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
    $response = $event->getResponse();
    $response->headers->set('Some-Header', 'some value'); 
  }

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::RESPONSE][] = array('onRespond');
    return $events;
  }
}
```

Note in the above code all use statements have been excluded, also you need to register your class as a event_subscriber service, this is done in your module's `module_name.services.yml` file like this:

```
services:
  name_of_service:
    class: Drupal\Full\Namespaced\Path\To\Class
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

You can add arguments (other services) that your class will depend on in the services file like normally.

Comment: Good answer, but worth mentioning that you only need this if you need to alter/extend responses created by someone else. If you return the response yourself, just call those methods directly. And if you want to do it as part of something that returns a render array (a block, a field, whatever), you can use #attached: `$build['#attached']['http_header'][] = [['Content-Type', 'application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8']];` (example is from `\Drupal\Core\Render\AttachmentsResponseProcessorInterface::processAttachments`)

Comment: Another example can be found at: https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/how-to-register-event-subscriber-drupal8