# How to set Header in file?

Tags: 8

Basically, How to port following function in Drupal 8?

```
drupal_add_http_header('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . $filename);
```

**Note**: I went through "[Replacement for drupal_add_http_header()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/198850/39516)", but my requirement is different. I need to download a file on form submit button.

Comment: I went through the link you mentioned. My requirement is different. I need to download a file on form submit button.

Comment: Just use the same technique with whatever headers you want to use to force a download. The answer is the same for all headers that you can send

Comment: @Clive, I did not understand much in that thread, I want to avoid event and response. I want to download file in Drupal 8. Can i get answer of that in this thread?

Comment: I don't know what you mean - to force download of a file, you need to set headers, like in your example. The linked example is how you set headers in Drupal 8. There isn't a different answer